# Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'"

Tags: javascript, html, content-security-policy

My Html file looks like below. When I launch the HTML file it says, content security policy is broken. How do I fix it from the HTML side?

```
<html>

<head>

  <title></title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="URLCode.js"></script>

<body onload='window.location.replace(URLalter(window.location.href));'>
</body>

</html>
```

Js code:

```
function URLalter(entryURL) {
  var entryPoint= entryURL+" ";
  return entryPoint;
}
```

Comment: Yes Tom..I have edited with js code.

Comment: Are you running this on the file protocol and not http?

Comment: No, this is running on HTTP protocol only

Comment: So your headers are preventing it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src#unsafe_inline_script

Comment: You should not name a method URL because there is one already https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL

Comment: @epascarello I tried with different name as well. I just edited there while posting a question. Still same issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240208/discussion-between-rongali-ramunaidu-and-epascarello).

Answer (score -2):

**How do I fix it from the HTML side?**

Easy answer, you don't. The server is most definitely responsible for this and with good reason but let's say those reasons are simply security. You may bypass this by adjusting your headers but it will not be done on a client level side at all!

That's bad.

You can maybe get comfortable with these security features often applied and understand the different headers/measures taken:
contentSecurityPolicy,
dnsPrefetchControl,
expectCt,
frameguard,
hidePoweredBy,
hsts,
ieNoOpen,
noSniff,
permittedCrossDomainPolicies,
referrerPolicy,
and xssFilter

Comment: My suggestion would be avoid these coding practices as we enter secure HTTP more and more; the work around is using event listeners which ensures the code 100% came from your site.